# renaming sheets with "full sheet" charts on them causes spreadsheet to reload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets allows charts to be moved to their own sheet.  Google scripts appears to be unable to rename these sheets though, without crashing the spreadsheet and forcing it to reload.

To see what I mean try this:
1) create new spreadsheet and put some data in it.
2) create any type of chart w/ the data.
3) edit the chart and select "Move To Own Sheet..."
4) create a script w/ the following code:

```
  function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    sheets[1].setName('bob');
  }
```

5) run the script and the spreadsheet crashes with the message: "Unable to Load File"
6) reload the spreadsheet and notice that the sheet did get renamed.

Why does the spreadsheet crash? Is it possible to rename the sheet w/o crashing?

Comment: this looks like a bug. Have you try sending a report?

Comment: no bug report yet.  wanted to see what stackoverflow could come up with first.

Comment: the execution transcript looks fine even when the spreadsheet crashes:
[18-05-31 15:42:15:410 PDT] Starting execution
[18-05-31 15:42:15:417 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[18-05-31 15:42:15:465 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.047 seconds]
[18-05-31 15:42:15:555 PDT] Sheet.setName([bob]) [0.089 seconds]
[18-05-31 15:42:15:557 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.139 seconds total runtime]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the clear reason of the crash. But I think that there is a workaround for avoiding the crash. So how about this workaround? In this workaround, it uses Sheets API. In order to use Sheets API, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services and API console. About the how to enable them, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605735/delete-all-filer-criterias-but-preserve-filter/50614501#50614501).

The sample script using Sheets API is as follows.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var sheetId = ss.getSheets()[1].getSheetId();
  var resource = {"requests":[{"updateSheetProperties":{"properties":{"sheetId":sheetId,"title":"bob"},"fields":"title"}}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, id);
}
```

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Using the API works.  Thank you.  Hopefully google can fix the issue w/ renaming directly in the future.

Comment: @user2179367 I think so. And thank you, too. I could also study from your question.